# In Rhythmbox, is there a way to sort by artist and search by title?

Tags: rhythmbox

In Rhythmbox I sort my music by artist. When I quickly want to look for a song I'd like to type in the title of the song. Not in the standard search box up top, but by starting to type when I've clicked anywhere in the list of songs. A small search box appears in the right bottom corner just like it does in Nautilus. The thing is, when I sort by artist that search looks up the artist as well. When I sort by title, it searches by title.

I'd like to sort by artist and search by title, but **not using the standard search feature**. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing more than simple. In fact, you should not necessarily use the small search box.

[image: Rhythmbox]

Now, to search by title or whatever you want, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and type the text to search.

To play the first track that was found, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>.

[image: search and play Rhythmbox]

After you find what you needed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to clear the search field text and remove all filters in the browser.

To know more about Rhythmbox's shortcut keys, when you are in Rhythmbox window, go to **Help** > **Contents** (or press <kbd>F1</kbd>) and select **Shortcuts** link.